# How to create Drop down from database in Codeigniter

Tags: php, jquery, codeigniter

Sorry, i want the create Form input using drop down from database. but i've try to created and error like this.

[image]

My Code in controller

```
   public function ajax_add()
{
    $data = array(
    'date_man_activity_ra' => $this->input->post('date_man_activity_ra',TRUE),
    'dd_user' => $this->mymodel->dd_user(),
    'user_selected' => $this->input->post('id_user') ? $this->input->post('id_user') : '',
    'id_user' => $this->input->post('id_user',TRUE),
    'note' => $this->input->post('note',TRUE),
        );
    $insert = $this->Man_activity->save($data);
    echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE));
}
```

and mymodel

```
public function dd_user()
{
    // ambil data dari db
    $this->db->order_by('id_user', 'asc');
    $result = $this->db->get('ops_user');

    // bikin array
    // please select berikut ini merupakan tambahan saja agar saat pertama
    // diload akan ditampilkan text please select.
    $dd[''] = 'Please Select';
    if ($result->num_rows() > 0) {
        foreach ($result->result() as $row) {
        // tentukan value (sebelah kiri) dan labelnya (sebelah kanan)
            $dd[$row->id_user] = $row->username;
        }
    }
    return $dd;
}
```

and my View

```
<div class="modal fade" id="modal_form" role="dialog">
<div class="modal-dialog">
    <div class="modal-content">
        <div class="modal-header">
            <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
            <h3 class="modal-title">Person Form</h3>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-body form">
            <form action="#" id="form" class="form-horizontal">
                <input type="hidden" value="" name="id"/> 
                <div class="form-body">
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">date_man_activity_ra</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="date_man_activity_ra" placeholder="yyyy-mm-dd" class="form-control datepicker" type="text">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Id User</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                        <?php
                        $dd_user_attribute = 'class="form-control select2"';
                        echo form_dropdown('id_user', $dd_user, $user_selected, $dd_user_attribute);
                        ?>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                    <div class="form-group">
                        <label class="control-label col-md-3">Note</label>
                        <div class="col-md-9">
                            <input name="note" placeholder="note" class="form-control" type="text">
                            <span class="help-block"></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </form>
        </div>
        <div class="modal-footer">
            <button type="button" id="btnSave" onclick="save()" class="btn btn-primary">Save</button>
            <button type="button" class="btn btn-danger" data-dismiss="modal">Cancel</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

how to solve it? or Another ways?

Thank You

Comment: what method in your controller that handles the data that needs to be thrown to the view where your form dropdown is located?

Answer (score 0):

```
public function ajax_add()
{
    $data = array(
    'date_man_activity_ra' => $this->input->post('date_man_activity_ra',TRUE),
    'dd_user' => $this->mymodel->dd_user(),
    'user_selected' => $this->input->post('id_user') ? $this->input->post('id_user') : '',
    'id_user' => $this->input->post('id_user',TRUE),
    'note' => $this->input->post('note',TRUE),
        );
    $insert = $this->Man_activity->save($data);
     // Load your view and pass the data that you use in dropdown

    //echo json_encode(array("status" => TRUE)); // Remove it
}
```